# Scroll div inside div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a huge amount of text inside an outer div. The inner div contains a bunch of div itself I am using to format the article.

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;" id="article_area">
  <div id="always_visible_stuff">
  </div>
  <div style="overflow: auto;" id="outer_div">
    <div id="inner_div">
      <div id="formatter1">
      ...
      </div>
      <div id="formatter2">
      ...
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This displays a scrollbar, but I cannot scroll. Somehow the outer div doesn't seem to get the height of the inner div. What do I have to do to get a working scrollbar?

Comment: is this inline css the only css you have ? If not, please post the css related to that html or a fiddle to see the bug in situation

Comment: The actual code is a lot more complicated, but this is the essential area of it.

You can find the page at http://www.brockart.de/new/index-2.html .

Click on "Artikel" to see what the code currently does (and does not).

Comment: You have to specify a height on the element you want to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Set a height value on your `.article-data` element. Like for example :

```
<div class="article-data" id="article-data" style="overflow: auto;height: 100vh;">
```